# Is there any way to convert JSON to model easier in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a JSON string that I need to map into a Model in C++. My current practice is define data type of the variable and get the value of JSON via key then assign to model one by one. Here is the code：

```
auto code = BaseModel::intValue(data, "code");

int BaseModel::intValue( const std::unordered_map<std::string, Value>& value, const std::string& key )
{
    return (value.find( key ) != value.end() && BaseModel::isBasicType(value.at(key))) ? value.at(key).asInt() : 0;
}
```

Is there any easy way to convert JSON to model? Maybe I just need define a header file with the model‘s data type, then it can help me convert JSON to model object.Instead of creating a model object, assign value to the model object from JSON one by one. I know there is a way in Objective-C：

```
// JSON:
{
    "uid":123456,
    "name":"Harry",
    "created":"1965-07-31T00:00:00+0000"
}

// Model:
@interface User : NSObject
@property UInt64 uid;
@property NSString *name;
@property NSDate *created;
@end
@implementation User
@end


// Convert json to model:
User *user = [User yy_modelWithJSON:json];

// Convert model to json:
NSDictionary *json = [user yy_modelToJSONObject];
```

Comment: Did you use one text block containing a json data file and code from two different languages? Also you don't "convert" from a data file to a programming language, you write code in the language to read the data file. (or in the case of json, use established libraries, see documentation)

Answer (score 0):

I've had great success with the [Nlohmann Json](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#arbitrary-types-conversions) library, which allows you to define a single set of serialization and deserialization functions, and then freely convert from your chosen structure to json and back.